# MikTeX broken after update; compiler seems to be dead

Tags: pdftex, miktex, tex-core, texworks, texniccenter

I use the latest Windows 10.

One month ago, my TeXnicCenter was working completely fine with MikTeX. Now, it occurred to me that MikTeX was slightly outdated. I had not updated it for about six months, so I updated and upgraded it via the MikTeX Console. During the updating, several error boxes occurred. After choosing another repository, the updating resumed without further errors. I updated and upgraded all packages as well as MikTeX itself, both in user mode and in admin mode, until no more new updates were available.

Now, .tex files cannot be compiled anymore, neither through TeXnicCenter, nor via command line, nor via TeXworks.

You can see the output of TeXnicCenter as well as the used profile settings in the screenshot.

[image: TeXnicCenter just returns nothing]

My question is the cause of this malfunction and how it can be solved.

Here is an example of command-line execution:
[image]

Here is the result of trying to repair the links:
[image]

Comment: create a small hello world document and compile it on the command line to get a sensible error message.

Comment: I did do this and the result is just nothing. No reaction.

Comment: show the screenshot of the call on the command line.

Comment: have edited above

Comment: hm, try to repair the links with `initexmf --admin --mklinks` or even `initexmf --force --mklinks --admin`

Comment: I would try a portable MikTeX, without uninstall your actual setup.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , I have restarted the computer now and tried your advice. See the results in the edit above.
Now, the hello world file can be compiled to pdf from the shell, but TeXnicCenter does not work yet.
Additionally, the miktex console is broken now, too. If I try to open miktex console, Windows tells me miktex-console.exe cannot be found.

Comment: why on earth are you compiling with admin rights?  Search your system for the path of the exe and then repair the windows shortcut. Check also the path variable. And at best remove every absolute path from texniccenter. It should find the applications by windows methods and not with fix pathes.

Comment: Sorry Ulrike, I didn't care about admin or non-admin. Sorry.

I have now, incidentally, found the cause and solution of the problem. 
Cause: It seems that during updating/upgrading from another repository, miktex was (somehow, but why?) installed completely anew at a distinct directory path. And the old installation was archived.

Solution: I have redefined the compiler path in texniccenter to the new miktex installation, and now it works fine.

Comment: well you should care about admin or not. From your screenshot it looks as if the older miktex was installed in a user location (and so probably as non-admin in single user mode) and second one in C:\program files with admin rights.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, @UlrikeFischer. (As it is my private computer anyway, and I am the only user without additional user profiles, I thought this admin/non-admin doesn't matter. And honestly it is the first time in my life that it makes a difference.) If you want you can post an answer and I will vote you up. Otherwise, big thx.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 2022.03.27
My problem with MikTeX was related to having installed "for all users 32-bit" a number of years ago and forgotten about it (having ignored the discouraging message at that time)
Now, I installed the x64 version for me alone. This caused failure with the bad parameter message. This also caused an attempt to uninstall to fail.
Solution was to use powershell (gcm pdflatex, for example) to find that the old 32-bit install was still there, and that it had been corrupted. I then download the 32-bit miktex and installed it for all users over the top of the old one, making the existing install the one and only. Commands then worked.
Using the miktex console, it would likely be possible to uninstall the all-users install and install a single user install. Since it now is working, I left well-enough alone.
Bad parameter messages can be to to 32 -- x64 mismatch.